# Sqlite over a network share

Tags: sqlite

Does anyone have real world experience running a Sqlite database on an SMB share on a LAN (Windows or Linux)?

Its clear from the [documentation](http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork) that this is not really the fastest way to share a Sqlite database.

The obvious caveats are that it may be slow, and Sqlite only supports a single thread writing to the DB at a time. So you become a lot less concurrent cause your DB updates now will block the DB for longer (DB will be locked while data is in transit over the network).

For my application the amount of data that I would like to share is fairly small and writes are not too frequent (a few writes every few seconds at most).

What should I watch out for? Can this work?

I know this is not what Sqlite was designed for, I am less interested in a Postgres/MySql/Sql Server based solution as I am trying to keep my app a light as possible with a minimal amount of dependencies.

Related Links:

From the [sqlite mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg37281.html), so I guess one big question is how unreliable are the filelock apis over SMB (windows or linux)

Comment: looks like linux samba may have oplocks enabled depending on its configuration. The more I look at this problem the less comfortable using this a solution, it can easily become a support nightmare

Comment: I have been using SQLite on a network shared drive for many months now with no problems. I created a JAVA Swing App that access the data concurrently for about 25 users that use it all day long with not a single problem. I think that when you design your app you should make sure to connect and disconnect every time you use it, so that you don't get any record locking issues. SQLite works great!

Comment: Will the locking work over SSHFS?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

My experience of file based databases (i.e. those without  a database server process), which goes back over twenty years, is that if you try to share them, they will *inevitably* eventually get corrupted. I'd strongly suggest you look at MySQL again.

And please note, I am not picking on SQLite - I use it myself, just not as a shared database.

Comment: yeah im toying with the idea of sharing this information over sockets with a peer to peer network. there are too many things that can go wrong with an embedded db over network share.

Answer (score 10):

You asked for real-world experience. Here's some:

SQLite locking is robust, ASSUMING the underlying (networked) file system is also robust. Historically, that's been a poor assumption. Recent operating systems get it much better.

If you play by the rules, your biggest problem will be cases where the database stays "locked" for many minutes at a stretch. For example, if the network drops an "unlock" request from a reader, you might be unable to write until the lock expires. If an "unlock" from a writer goes missing, you'll be unable to read. (To be fair, you can experience the same problems with ordinary documents.)

You'll get fewer problems on a good reliable network with "opportunistic locking" (client-level file caching) disabled for the database.

Comment: Also: a long-running process that forgets to either commit or roll-back timely can be very frustrating to debug, because you can't tell who or what holds the lock.

Answer (score 9):

Well I am not great sqlite expert but I believe the Locking of records/tables may not work correctly and may make database corrupt. Because since there is no single server which maintains central locking, two sqlite dll instances on different machines sharing same file over network may not work correctly at all. If database is opened on same machine, sqlite may use file level locking offered by OS to maintain integrity but I doubt if it works correctly over network share.

Answer (score 9):

> "If you have many client programs accessing a common database over a
>   network, you should consider using a client/server database engine
>   instead of SQLite. SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but
>   because of the latency associated with most network filesystems,
>   performance will not be great. Also, the file locking logic of many
>   network filesystems implementation contains bugs (on both Unix and
>   Windows). If file locking does not work like it should, it might be
>   possible for two or more client programs to modify the same part of
>   the same database at the same time, resulting in database corruption.
>   Because this problem results from bugs in the underlying filesystem
>   implementation, there is nothing SQLite can do to prevent it."

from https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

that also applies for any kind of file-based databases like `Microsoft Access`