# sqlite over network share for failover

Tags: sqlite, network-share

As a follow-up of this question: [sqlite-over-a-network-share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788517/sqlite-over-a-network-share)

If I put the SQlite DB on a network share, but will not access it concurrently from different machines. I only have the SQLite db stored on a share so a cluster of failover computers can take over where one machine left off.

Are there any inherent problems with that approach?

Comment: The only issue I see is if the network-share goes down, and recuperating whatever operations were missed. Not very helpful, sorry, that's why I'm adding it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: mpelletier: you make a valid point though. The reason why I opted for SQLite in the first place is to have a high available (and fast) datastore. One which is not relying on a network connection.
If I put the DB on a share, I loose a big reason to go with SQlite in the first place.

Comment: Which makes me wonder how SQlite and (automatic) failover scenarios work anyway.

Comment: See http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Answer (score 2):

Interested in knowing your experiences (After 5 years). Per Eric Grange's helpful hint:

- "SQLite uses POSIX advisory locks to implement locking on Unix"... "POSIX advisory locking is known to be buggy or even unimplemented on many NFS implementations"  ... "Your best defense is to not use SQLite for files on a network filesystem."
- Having said that, if your NFS server is rock-solid (ie, NetApp) and your clients are rock-solid (ie, probably not Linux; see for instance http://nfsworld.blogspot.co.at/2006/10/review-of-why-nfs-sucks-paper-from.html).
- POSIX advisory locking over NFS is also impelmentation-dependent: From the File locking Wikipedia article: "On Linux prior to 2.6.12, flock calls on NFS files would act only locally. Kernel 2.6.12 and above implement flock calls on NFS files using POSIX byte-range locks. These locks will be visible to other NFS clients that implement fcntl-style POSIX locks, but invisible to those that do not." If there's doubt, you can use `nfstrace` to determine what your OS is trying to do.
- What happens if node A has begun a transaction, locked the table-file, then crashed? Will node B see the advisory lock and refuse to write to the file?

Comment: I never used this method. So no experiences.

Comment: Does anybody happen to know if sqlite uses "fcntl-style POSIX locks"?