# How do I give a connection string to a server on a network?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, connection-string, app-config

I'm using SQLite so it's only a file, not a server, but here's the plan:

Install the application + the physical .sqlite file on a machine and on another machine over the network, let the other user connect to the .sqlite file.

So I'd have to share that folder and give it permissions to allow everyone to read and write from it.

Here's my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ColegioMentorEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Repositories.ColegioMentor.csdl|res://*/Repositories.ColegioMentor.ssdl|res://*/Repositories.ColegioMentor.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\ColegioMentor.sqlite&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

It seems I CAN change the connection string! Great! But how do I reference a networked location in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788517/sqlite-over-a-network-share), you may want to consider using something like MySQL if you need to support more than a single user, due to potential corruption issues that can arise when you access SQLite concurrently.

Though SQLite does support concurrent access, there are several caveats that you can read about on their [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) (see items 5 and 6).

From that page:

> sharing an SQLite database between two
>   or more Windows machines might cause
>   unexpected problems

Comment: Hm... you scared me. Would you suggest using RSync to continually sync the two physical files on each computer daily? That way each user has the latest version.

Comment: I would suggest using MySQL or PostgreSQL instead of SQLite, since they are designed to support scenarios like yours.

Comment: I don't know much about SQLite myself either - good thing you pointed out some of the limitations. I'd probably agree with @ElectricDialect on this one and go for a full-fledged DBMS. Microsoft SQL Server Express is also an option - it's free and available here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is a standard UNC path, like:

> \\ServerName\ShareName\Database.sqlite

I hope this helps!

Comment: In your answer, "ShareName" would be the name of the shared folder, correct?

Comment: Yessir! You would then give the users you want to have access to that share read/write permissions, and you should be golden!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the ShareName, it would be the **shared** name of the shared folder, as shown in the properties dialog > Shared Tab > share name, not the windows explorer folder name (assuming you're using windows).