# Common File on Server

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

I created an app. Its copy will be in two different computers. But a **sqlite** database file needs to be common for these two apps. I mean, both computers will be able to read and write this database file. For this purpose, I will put this file in a folder on our server which both computers are connected to. How can I get the full path for this file in Python? Or can you suggest any other way as easy as possible for doing this task?

Comment: Make one of the two applications offer the database connection on an open port?

Comment: Are you sure the data base file can have concurrent access from 2 different processes and works over a network share? Many database engines don't like such things. What kind of database / OS?

Comment: "How can I get the full path for this file in Python?" Why aren't you simply providing this as a parameter.  Almost universally, SQLite database file paths are provided as configuration parameters.  Why not follow this pattern?

Answer (score 3):

[Sqlite over a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788517/sqlite-over-a-network-share) [stackoverflow.com]

I'd recommend against database files on a network drive. The network filesystem usually isn't robust enough to handle random updates like a DB.

As a previous answer suggested, you'd be better off creating a simple client/server model. A server process has sole access to the sqlite db, clients send requests to the server. Don't pass the sqlite db file back and forth.

You might want to use a full network DB such as MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a Python server program running on the server with the database file (using the sockets library).  Then have the two clients connect to the server program (again, using the sockets library), and then receive the database file.  You can find some examples for the socket library at http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/07/socket-programming-tutorial.html