# SQLite Database not showing updates in Manager

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi, sqlitestudio

I am running a Setup where I have a SQLite DB on my Raspberry Pi and I would like to open it remotely via a Database Manager like SQLiteStudio. I have setup a samba server on my raspberry and shared the .db file. Now I want to open the file on my PC. So far I have tried it and if I open the Database I can see all the entrys, but if I change anything in the database I dont see the changes in SQLiteStudio. Even after a refresh. It works just fine if I have the file on my PC. To see the changes I made in the Database I have to delete the db from SQLiteStudio and add it again. Any clues or other Management programs that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended against using SQLite databases over samba shares. See this answer for more details: [Sqlite over a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788517/sqlite-over-a-network-share)

It is known to cause inconsistent results and issues.